# How To Get Datepicker(Kendo) Value On Load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using "DatePickerFor" control in my project...
Date value is already defined, before load.

```
@Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.DateOfBirth).Name("DateOfBirth").Format("dd/MM/yyyy").Animation(true).Events(e => e.Change("DateOfBirth_Change"))
```

Everything works fine, but now i need to get the value in javascript...For some reason value is empty:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var input = document.getElementById("DateOfBirth").value;//here i get empty string
}
```

I can get value of other controls in "ready" function, but datepicker still returns an empty string.
Could someone tell me, why? Thanks

Comment: use $("#DateOfBirth").val();

Comment: $("#DateOfBirth").val(); is still an empty string

Comment: add your generated html cod for Dateoicker

Comment: Do you see the widget being generated? Does the date picker open when you click the input?

Comment: Sure... I'm calculating an age using that control. It's works on datepicker change function... Also it works when i try to get value after page load e.g. on click button

Comment: Please post the generated HTML.

Comment: <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date of Birth: must be a date." data-val-required="*" id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" type="date" /><script>
 jQuery(function(){jQuery("#DateOfBirth").kendoDatePicker({"change":DateOfBirth_Change,"format":"dd/MM/yyyy","parseFormats":["dd/MM/yyyy"],"min":new Date(1900,0,1,0,0,0,0),"max":new Date(2099,11,31,0,0,0,0)});});
</script>
                <span id="AgeSpan" style="padding-left: 25px;"></span>
<!-- It's a generated html -->

Comment: Open up the developer tools of your browser and write `$("#DateOfBirth")`. Does it find the element? If yes, write `$("#DateOfBirth").data("kendoDatePicker")` and see if that returns the widget object.

Comment: done... both returns an objects correctly

Comment: Are your sure then that you set the `$(document).ready()` in the right place?

Comment: Thank you Andrei!!! I had "$(document).ready()" fucntion in separate "js" file... Now i have replaced it to the same page at the bottom and it works... But what's the reason?

Comment: The other file was probably not referenced by your document. For this reason, it couldn't file the element (the element didn't exist in that specific document). I don't know your file/document structure so I can't really say anything more. If the file was actually referenced by your page, it might have already been executed (before the date picker initialization).

Comment: Right, but it's very strange, because i was receiving values in "js" file of the other controls except datepicker